# command not found when do "yiic rresque start"

Tags: php, yii

I need to start resque.
I saw in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-resque/ and did it.

But when I run command "yiic rresque start", It shown "-bash: yiic: command not found"
How's to fix it?

Comment: try with `sh yiic rresque start`

Comment: make sure yiic file in dir where you run command

Comment: You have to be in that directory where yiic file is present.

Comment: I try with sh yiic rresque start in framework directory but it show:

         yiic: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory

         yiic: line 3: /bin: is a directory

         yiic: line 4: 0,: command not found

         yiic: line 5: 0,: command not found

         yiic: line 6: 0,: command not found

         yiic: line 7: 0,: command not found

         yiic: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

         yiic: line 8: ` * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>'

Comment: make sure to use stable version, read above points again

Answer (score 1):

you will need to navigate to your protected folder

```
/var/www/yoursite/protected
```

and then you have to type

```
php yiic rresque start
```

it should work perfectly.